# How to install g++ 4.9.2 in Cent OS 6.5?

Tags: linux

I am trying to install the latest version of g++ in Cent OS. The best I managed is the following:

```
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-2.repo
yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-binutils
yum install devtoolset-2-gcc-c++ devtoolset-2-binutils
```

But this installs g++ 4.8.2 and not 4.9.2. Is there a way to install 4.9.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to do it the old fashioned way. Get the GCC sources, build it by hand.

Any reason you are averse to doing this? (I can think of a few, but unless you do too, I don't want to add anything that might be confusing).

If you are hesitant to build from sources, I can probably provide some steps.

NOTE: The reason for that is the devtools with 4.9 is currently only available to Red Hat users with a valid license. Wait for a while, and eventually I am sure 4.9 devtools will be made available to CentOS users too like 4.8 is currently.

Comment: thanks for answering, it seems like I will wait for this. Can you please help me here also: http://superuser.com/questions/834915/how-to-build-freetype-on-cent-os-6-5

Answer (score 28):

CentOS 6/7 officially supports this. You don't need third party repository. And gcc version is 4.9.2 in CentOS's repo.

```
yum install centos-release-scl-rh          
yum install devtoolset-3-gcc devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
```

To use the updated tools, start a new shell using the `scl` command:

```
scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

You may also need to reset your PATH environment variable, which might be set in ~/.bashrc or other profile file. If you need to change it, it should point to `/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/:$PATH`

More information on the [SCL from CentOS](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) and from [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html-single/1.0_Release_Notes/index.html)

Comment: This didn't work for me. After those 3 steps completed seemingly successful, I still see gcc 4.7.2 when i do `gcc -v`

Comment: Ok, in addition to these steps, I had to change my .bashrc file so that my PATH environment variable was set to `/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/:$PATH` rather than `/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/:$PATH`. Then after a session restart it worked.

Comment: After using this solution I see that the gcc version really updated (using gcc --version), but I still see the header files from the old version. Moreover, I cannot find most of the newer headers in the directory I expected them to be (/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/include/). Why can this happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: To make this answer stand the test of time, add `yum search devtoolset | grep gcc-c++` to reveal the correct number instead of 3 as in the answer

Answer (score 14):

I use Scientific Linux Cern 6 repository to install gcc 4.9 and g++ 4.9 on my CentOS 6.5 and CentOS 6.6 systems. It does not install g++ 4.9.2. It installs g++ 4.9.1 instead which is good enough for my needs.

Here are the commands I use to install it.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/scl/slc6-scl.repo
yum -y --nogpgcheck install devtoolset-3-gcc devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
```

As Michael said in his comment to this post, to actually use the version of gcc that this installs, start a new shell with the following command.

```
scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

Comment: To actually use the version of gcc that this installs, start a new shell using `scl enable devtoolset-3 bash`

Comment: @Michael Thank you for mentioning this. I have included your comment in my answer now to make the answer more helpful.

Comment: Also didn't work for me. Same as for Jesse's answer