# How to build freetype on Cent OS 6.5?

Tags: linux

I am trying to build the freetype library I got from here: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.5.3.tar.gz But I am really failing to do so.

I am using Cent OS 6.5, and the compiler is g++ 4.8.2. I need the library to be release, static and 64 bit. Is there anyone who can explain this in simple steps, please?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? What error messages did you receive? Can you provide more details as to the steps you used, the commands you executed and the results you got?

For the record, I just tried to do a "./configure --prefix=/tmp/freetype && make && make install" (the holy trinity of building from sources, if you will) and everything seems to work fine.